# Built application installer now only works on the Mac OS it was built on

Tags: macos

After updating our Signing Certificate, it seems that our Application Installer will now only work on the version of Mac OS it was built on.

Our build machine has OS 10.15.3.

The installer works fine on Macs that have 10.15.

On ALL other versions of the OS we've tried (10.14, 11, 12) it displays a "Package Missing" msg rather than the icon for the package.

UPDATE: did more testing:
Works on:   10.15.4, 11.??.??
Fails on:    10.14.6, 11.6.4, 12

How can this be fixed?

We didn't change our build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a combination of several things:

1. Some of the scripts were dumping console output to /dev/nul.  Guess where some error messages were going...
2. Some of our test systems don't care if the DMG isn't signed.  (Gotta find the relevant settings to fix that.)
3. Our Certificates were corrupted somehow.  Had to delete them and re-install them.